# Displaying Facebook posts to non-Facebook users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to pull Facebook content (specifically wall posts from a public page) to display on a website without Facebook requiring a user login? Before the offline_access permission was deprecated, I would simply create a token as myself, store it, and pull the information as needed.

Now, from what I can figure out, the only two options I have are to 1) manually update that token every 60 days, or 2) display the content only to Facebook users AND make them "allow" the app. Obviously #1 is not a preferred option, and #2 doesn't seem like very good practice.

For reference, I'm only trying to pull content from a publically accessible page wall and require no action on behalf of the user (no wall posting, no reading stream, etc).

This seems like a really simple concept, and I feel like I have to be missing something. I can't find an answer anywhere. Are these really my only two options? Any feedback would be much appreciate.

**Updated:**

I think I may have found a way around this. With offline_access being deprecated, there is an fb_exchange_token option available to extend the expiration of an existing token. With a call to the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret=
{app_secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={existing_token}
```

you should receive a token with an extended expiration. In my scenario, I will allow the app through my own Facebook account, store the token in my PHP code, and just use cURL to periodically update the existing code.

*Note: According to the Facebook documentation, the expiration can only be extended once per day*

Comment: _Before the offline_access permission was deprecated, I would simply create a token as myself, store it, and pull the information as needed._
Then if you change your password or your session change for security reasons you need to get another access token again & i'm not sure it be possible after deprecating offline access (i think it be available again)

Comment: @korysharp Did this work for you? I am trying to do the same thing.  Do you have an example of how you accomplished this?

Comment: @MicFin I am currently using https://graph.facebook.com/{page_url}/feed?access_token={app_token} where page_url is the url of the page (ie: cocacola) and app_token represents an Application Access token. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948809/trying-to-get-app-access-token for instructions on obtaining one of these. I've been able to store and use this single token (which has no expiration) for all of our websites. Hope this helps.

Comment: @KorySharp that works excellent but I did run into an issue.  For some users it works fine but when I use it on other users I receive the error

Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 803, message: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (benaffleck) [HTTP 404]
from /Users/Raevynheart/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/koala-1.10.0/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb:503:in `block in graph_call' 

any suggestions?

Comment: @McFin this method will only work for pages that have public access (no privacy settings). The pages that i use this for in my cases are clients of ours that have public pages. Is the Ben Affleck account a "page" or a regular user account?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you own the page you can use the manage_pages permission. The manage_pages permission is a permanent token from what I can gather. Then use /feed on the graph api with the relevant page number to pull the information.

I am assuming you own this page. If you don't or aren't explicitly given permission then you don't have the rights to pull this information down.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something incorrectly, this is not the case. I just obtained a token with the read_stream and manage_pages permissions. The token expires in 4238 seconds (a little over an hour). I know that there are individual tokens for each page that you own that you can access through the open graph api @ /me/accounts, but these page tokens expire at the same time as the token used to obtain these keys.

Comment: What about if you get the publish_stream permission. I have used that in my app and I know it doesn't expire. Or I have at least had it several months and its still going.

Comment: There use to be an offline_access permission that doesn't exist anymore. I have a handful of sites that use tokens that I obtained with offline_access (and still work), but this is no longer an option.

Comment: Yes I was aware offline_access was depreciated but it isn't necessary with publish_stream and publish_stream requires offline access hence you get the permission of offline access so to speak by default.

Comment: No dice. I just did a token request for publish_stream only... still has an expiration under 5000 seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. I've attempted to use appID|appSecret as an access token, and while that doesn't give an invalid token error, it yields no results (returns an empty data set) regardless of what kind of call I am making.

Comment: @Adam, `publish_stream` is not the same as `read_stream` and read_stream goes away with the expiry of the access token. While `publish_stream` will live on.

Comment: Do you have the read_stream as @DMCS suggested. They are right in that publish only writes. I was only suggesting publish to get a non-expiring token.