# Access to public photos through Platform API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, photo

This is a question asked in several ways - it is possible to view public photos from NON FRIENDS through the Facebook page (www.facebok.com) if you are logged in - and permission of the photo is set to public by the owner - but it is not possible with the Graph API, or FQL.

This seems to be by design, but would be very nice if this would be possible as well. There are two bugs open right now (triaged, assigned), perhaps this will be reconsidered:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/282804805117022?browse=search_4f5bbfcc2e0630400115238

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/245105075571349?browse=search_4f5bbfcc2e0630400115238

If I am mistaken I would be very happy for a work around.

EDIT:

These 3 methods give back no entries the user I query is a non-friend:

 
SELECT src_big, src, src_small FROM photo WHERE object_id = 'PhotoIdOfNonFriend' 

 
SELECT aid, name, object_id FROM album WHERE owner='NonFriendId'

 
https://graph.facebook.com/PhotoIdOfNonFriend

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but you can check out the question that I posted (and ended up figuring out) about accessing public info to non logged in users.

[Displaying Facebook posts to non-Facebook users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634608/displaying-facebook-posts-to-non-facebook-users) (check out the Updated section in my original post).

Comment: Thank you Kory. I believe this is another scenario - in my case the user is logged in and he is able to see public photos of non-friends inside facebook.com, but he is not able to retrieve the album or photo through FQL or Graph API with the queries mentioned above.