# Facebook access token for site feed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to loading a facebook feed from my webpage using:

https://graph.facebook.com/177610425663218/feed

For this I got an access token from the [Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). The problem is that the token keeps running out:

```
Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time ...
```

I know I could create a OAuth login to get a new token but I would like to show the feed on a webpage. I don't want to OAuth all visitors of the page. How do I get an constant access token for my site feed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily get an access token. Just create an app and login using `app_id` and `app_secret`:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=some_app_id&client_secret=the_appsecret');
$token = str_replace('access_token=', '', $response);
```

Works for me.

Comment: when feeding FacebookSession the token and executing a request I get: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Comment: @user2070775 please create a new question for your problem. otherwise you won't get any help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, it looks like they are [deprecating the offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/). Further down in the page it mentions extending the current token by 60 days. Perhaps that may help?

Comment: Can't I use my facebook account to generate a new access_token using php? Something like `file_get_content('facebook/login/getToken?username=bla&password=blub')`

Comment: You could, but if you invalidate the token (change password etc) you'll need to generate a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my post from a couple of days ago (look at me Updated section in the original post).

[Displaying Facebook posts to non-Facebook users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634608/displaying-facebook-posts-to-non-facebook-users)

Because the offline_access permission is being deprecated, you're going to have to programmatically swap out your token periodically (which does not require reauthorization). Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Just found it myself ;)