# Explain the Facebook access_token

Tags: javascript, facebook-access-token

This whole Facebook access_token thing is driving me nuts. All I want to do is fetch a user's public Facebook posts.

It used to work by simply doing:

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/posts?limit=LIMIT&callback=?', function (posts) {
    // Posts available in "posts" variable
});
```

But now I get the "access_token required" error.

Trust me; I've checked the docs, Googled all over and checked similar questions on SO but I'm really hoping there's a more straight forward way of doing this than what I've seen.

Do you *really* have to create a Facebook App (I don't even have an account), make the user "accept" the app and login etc for this to work?

With Twitter it's just as easy as it used to be with Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have to create a Facebook App (You need to have an account), make the user "accept" the app and login etc for this to work.

However you can search public posts of user (not a specific user) by facebook's public search api.

e.g.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=hello&type=post
```

This will search all posts with hello keyword in it.

**Reference** ( you need to have facebook account to see this page )

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

**Edit (after seeing comments):**

If you want to access public posts of your own page. You can pull it without any login from user (but you will need an access_token)

Generate an offline access_token from here,

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

Then you can use that token to pull data . Thus no need of logging on by user.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/wesellwine/posts?access_token=<access_token from graph api explorer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you ask me that's totally crazy. All I want to do (well, my client) is display their posts on their website. Why would a visitor need to accept that? What if the visitor doesn't have a Facebook account? I know I'm not the only one with this problem. I've managed to get it to work by using other people's access tokens (I understand this is far from ideal). But so far it's always stopped working after a while.

Comment: Because Facebook changed their privacy settings.  It's not that you can't still do that (as Jashwant pointed out), you just can't programmatically grab private information without the user's permission.  It's the same as if you visited someone's Facebook page you aren't friends with.  If their posts are not visible then it means they have configured their security that way and you need their permission.  Forcing you to create an App ensures the information requests are legitimate and traceable since it's very easy to dupe the average FB user into agreeing to a Yes/No dialog.

Comment: But I'm only after publicly available information. I could scrape the site and get the info I'm after but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: There's no point explaining why it does not allow. Its facebook policy. Its not twitter.Twitter is a public network. You can even search tweets on google.com. I dont think you can even scrape facebook without logging in.Also, if my answer helps you, mark it as answer.

Comment: The page I want to pull posts from is publicly available without logging in: http://www.facebook.com/wesellwine. That's why it's so annoying and strange. I find it hard to believe that I need to ask people who visit my site to log in to Facebook and connect my site to their Facebook account just so I can display my own publicly available posts - are you absolutely sure this is the only way? I'd prefer to keep the question open for now.

Comment: Don't you agree that requiring this process (user logging in, accepting, access tokens etc) to fetch my own publicly available posts but _not_ requiring it for fetching the entire planet's publicly available posts (https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=hello&type=post) is utter madness? I find it hard to believe but I have yet to find a straight forward solution.