# Explain many inner-most loops in FB.login to get the access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

My friend called this like lambda-calculus, even though I know some lambas -- I am still confused how the authorization really works to get the access token.

So please explain this code, hopefully line-by-line. Source of the example is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/).

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

*P.s. Trying to categorize things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905476/fb-object-javascript-sdk-oaauth-2-0-and-graph-api-with-console-logs), the q is a sub-problem.*

> **Perhaps related**
>
> 1. [Explain the Facebook access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970381/explain-the-facebook-access-token)
> 2. [Facebook get access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088676/facebook-get-access-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
```

FB is where all of the Facebooks functions live. All the methods are defined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ . Login in particular will popup a dialog asking the user to sign in or approve your app.

```
   if (response.authResponse) {
```

If they approve your app or have it already added, the response.authResponse will be populated. authResponse also has accessToken, expiry, and UserID. See more details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

```
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
```

This goes to Facebook to ask for the user who just approved/signed into your app. Now you can get the basic information about the user. All the available fields with permissions you need to get them are available here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

```
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
```

This is just getting the name from the user object that you recieved from the `/me` endpoint.

```
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
```

This means the user cancelled or did not approve your app so you cannot grab any of their information from Facebook.

```
   }
 });
```