# trying to get app access token

Tags: facebook, access-token

I tried to get an app-access-token for my facebook app with this code:

```
APP_ACCESS_TOKEN = FB.api(
    "oauth/access_token",
    {client_id: APP_ID, client_secret: APP_SECRET_CODE, redirect_uri: uri},
    function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

which should be like:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
       &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
       &redirect_uri=uri
```

but i get an error:

```
code: 1
message: "Missing authorization code"
type: "OAuthException"
```

What is the authorization code and how can i get it?

Comment: Sorry I can´t remember. Too long ago. It was during a lab.

Answer (score 70):

**Obtaining an App Access Token**

To obtain an App Access Token, invoke the following HTTP GET request:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials
```

The API will respond with a query-string formatted string of the form:

```
access_token=YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Comment: Updated link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

Comment: What is client_credentials ?

Comment: @VlasBashynskyi if you're asking what value you're suppose to enter there, you're not, it's not a placeholder it's the actual value you use. If you're asking what it does, not sure but probably let's facebook know you want client credentials of some sort.

Comment: As of 4/27/17 the api response format has changed and it's returning `{"access_token":"YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN","token_type":"bearer"}`

Comment: it's OK to expose the client (APP) secret?

Comment: I'm not sure that exposing the APP client secret in the code is a good idea, you can take the APP token from Facebook tool "Access Token Tool" just copy the token to your code https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

Comment: What could be the reason for not getting the access token sometimes?

Answer (score 45):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/:

> *“Because it requires you to include your App Secret you should not attempt to make this call client-side as that would expose this secret to all your app users. **It is important that your App Secret is never shared with anyone.** For this reason, this call should be performed server-side”*

And for the app access token, it’s the same – you should never *use* it client-side, because every user could spot it there and then start using it to perform actions on behalf of your app (or change many of your app’s settings).

If you have a server-side part to your application, you can simply “build” the app access token there yourself, concatenating app id and secret with a pipe symbol, `app_id|app_secret`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info how the access token is being created!

Comment: Can people still see it client side even if you hide your .js files?

Comment: Of course they can, there is no "hiding" of client-side scripts.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the sharing the `app_id|app_secret` concatenate method of having a **permanent access token**. I was looking for hours for an answer to this.

Comment: Do we need to submit the Facebook app to review incase we use app token (Permanent token)?. We are using this app token only to get the likes count Facebook page. There is user login at all.

Comment: @Jayaprakash: If you are not using any permissions and don’t even have user login implemented, then there of course is nothing to submit.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for your reply. But, when I use the app token of newly created Facebook app in the Graph API, the like count is not coming in response (API: https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE ID>?access_token=<APP TOKEN> ). When I use the app token of other Facebook apps which is already submitted for review and approved (has manage_pages permission enabled), it works. Since it is not documented clearly, we have a doubt that, do we need to send it for review by requesting mange_pages permission. Or does it requires any other permission?

Comment: You can not have an _app_ token with `manage_pages` permission. Is the page that you are trying to get the like count from public, and not restricted in any way (alcohol-related content, age, country, …)? If it is restricted, you can not use your app access token, you need to use a user access token for a user that is allowed to see it, or a page access token.

Comment: @CBroe: I have tested this in our testing page (http://facebook.com/knowdepage123), there is no restricted content in this. For this page, an app token of already existing Facebook app (which has manage_pages permission) works, but the app token of newly created Facebook app is not working. Recently, I have sent the app for review by requesting manage_pages permission, but they rejected our app as there is no Facebook login functionality in our app. Please help us how to proceed. Is there any contact for Facebook review team?

Comment: @Jayaprakash: This is getting a bit too broad here, for the context of the original question. May I suggest you create your own question, and describe the issue in there.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Created the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107620/do-review-required-if-we-want-to-get-facebook-page-like-count-without-facebook

Answer (score 1):

check if users of the node.js or the JAVASCRIPT.

```
getLongLiveToken: function(data){
    FB.api('oauth/access_token', {
        client_id: data.client_id, // FB_APP_ID
        client_secret: data.secret, // FB_APP_SECRET
        grant_type: 'fb_exchange_token',
        fb_exchange_token: data.access_token // USER_TOKEN
    }, function (res) {
        if (!res || res.error) {
            console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
        } else {
            var accessToken = res.access_token;
            if(typeof accessToken != 'undefined'){}
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that exposing the APP client secret in the code is a good idea, you can take the APP token from Facebook tool "Access Token Tool" just copy the token to your code for any use   https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this POST endpoint without generating the token, just be sure its being called from the server not client-side where the app_secret is exposed to public:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}&scrape=true&access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}
```