# How to add Facebook App's accessToken to GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest method?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I copied the code below from `Facebook Graph Api console`. However, Android Studio doesn't recognize `accessToken`.

I have alread created a `Facebook App` and I got its `acesstoken`. But I don't know where to add it in the code. If I just copy and paste. [It shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlB4Q.png)

If I use `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` method, it will show this error:

> errorMessage: An access token is required to request this resource

### **Here is my code:**

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
               accessToken,
                "/ibm/events",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: " + response.toString());
                    }});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name,cover,start_time,end_time,place,description");
        parameters.putString("limit", "3");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
```

Comment: AccessToken is the token string you get after you login your app with facebook. You need to pass the token to this method.

Comment: @AmadYus, thank you for the comment. Do you know what to do if I already have a Facebook app access token? I created an facebook app so that I don't need to use login. But I don't know how and where to add the accessToken that I got from that app.

Comment: Did you have 'login with facebook' kind of thing in your app? AccessToken is the token you got after login using facebook api, not the token you get from facebook developer console. For the question how to use that token, you just simply replace access token (in your case, the unrecognized accessToken) with the token that you got.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly :

Make a Facebook app with these simple steps I have written below:

1. Go to Developer tab and click on it.
2. Then go to Website Option.
3. Enter the app name which you have want.
4. Click on Create Facebook App.
   After this you have to choose category, you can choose App for Pages.
   Your AppId and Appkey is created automatically. The AppSecretKey is obfuscated. You can click on the show button to see your AppId and AppSecurityKey.

Then [Check this link to generate access token](https://www.slickremix.com/facebook-60-day-user-access-token-generator/)

1.Copy and Paste Your App ID & Your App Secret into the generator below. You can get your App ID & your App Secret by clicking on the Apps main menu option and then choosing your newely created App.

2. Next click the Tools Menu and then choose Graph API Exploer.
   page1
   On this page you will click the Graph API Explorer select option.
3. Then choose your Application from the list. In this example we'll use Custom Feed.
4. Now you click on the Get Access Token. This will show a Select Permissions popup as you will see next.
5. Next Click on the Extended Permissions menu option and click the checkbox read_stream and click Get Access Token. DO NOT CHECK read_stream if you are using our plugin to display a Page on facebook.

6.Then click the Okay button to continue.

Fetch Event IN Android : You have to download Android facebook sdk and put you access token there  getCurrentAccessToken() in this method.

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{event-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

[Event Details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event)

Comment: Thnak you for your response. I just made the Facebook app and now I have the accessToken. do I need to add the accessToken to my code above to make it work ? How and where do I add it ?

Comment: Yes you have to use that access token check facebook developer website  to use of access token.

Comment: please accept the answer if its help you.

Comment: Please help me. I have been looking for 6 hours to find out how to add the accessToken. I just need this step :-(. Can you give me a link to it ?

Comment: for what purpose you want to use facebook api .

Comment: please check my answer now.