# Do review required if we want to get Facebook Page like count (Without Facebook login) by Facebook app token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

I am doing a static web page in my website, in which I am showing the like count of particular Facebook page. There is no kind of login required to see this web page. Also, I don't want to user to login with their Facebook account to see the Facebook page like count.

I have implemented this requirement by using Facebook app token.

API: "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?access_token=APP_TOKEN"

But the problem here is, If I use the app token of already approved app by Facebook with some permissions (manage_pages) exists, it works. It is not working for the app token of newly created Facebook app.

I have sent the app for review to Facebook by requesting manage_pages permission, but they rejected the app and said that my website doesn't have the Facebook login functionality implemented.

Since it is not documented clearly, I have a doubt that do the app need to send for review if I want to get the Facebook page like count without Facebook login (By using Facebook app token)? If yes, what permission do I want to request?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to learn what Tokens there are:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

For your problem, you can just use an App Access Token. There is no need for any permission or Login Review, the links above tell you exactly how to create one. Make sure you never use the Token on the client, especially because it includes the App Secret. Do the API call on the server only (file_get_contents or curl, if you use PHP).

If by "it does not work" you mean that you only get the id and the name, then it´s not about "not working", you need to read the changelog and search for "Declarative Fields": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

So if you want to get more than just id and name, the API call would be like this: https://graph.facebook.com/936299239766048?access_token=YOURAPPTOKEN&fields=id,name,likes,...

Comment: Thanks. We have already looked into those. We used the token which is generated from this tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/. But it works for one app and not working for another app.  We have tried this for this page https://www.facebook.com/knowdepage123

Comment: i hope you used the APP token, not the USER token from that tool. that´s all i can say, i´d need a LOT more information for more help.

Comment: Yes. I am using the app token only. https://graph.facebook.com/936299239766048?access_token=YOURAPPTOKEN. Could you please create a sample app in Facebook and put the app token in the above API, then please let us know whether the like count works.

Comment: yes, works fine: 
   "name": "Knowde testing",
   "id": "936299239766048"
}

Comment: i have added some more info to my answer. you really need to learn how to write error descriptions, "it does not work" is not good enough. i am pretty sure it´s about declarative fields, but it´s hard to guess when you could just post exactly what response you get and what you mean with "does not work" - maybe next time ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for solution. Appending fields parameter as like you mentioned the answer, works great. This is what I want exactly. But this confusion came from, for some app token so many fields were came in response including likes without giving fields parameter in the API. That is weird. Anyway thanks for the reply, it works.