# Facebook PHP SDK: Unknown path components

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to validate Facebook App ID and App Secret. With Graph Explorer, I'm able to use access token in shape of {APP_ID}|{APP_SECRET} to get app details on /v2.5/{APP_ID} endpoint.

It doesn't work with PHP SDK though. The error I'm getting is:

> Unknown path components: /{APP_ID}

The code I used is this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook( [
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => '2.5',
] );

$facebook->get( '/' . $app_id, $app_id . '|' . $app_secret );
```

It does the validation, because with invalid app ID I'm getting:

> Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.

And with invalid secret:

> Invalid OAuth access token signature.

How can I get the app details just like in graph explorer? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, the request seems to be correct. Please help.

Comment: Did you actually replace `{APP_ID}` with your app id? If not that would explain why this is not working.

Comment: Yes I did. The problem was '2.5' instead of 'v2.5' :)

Comment: Ah, could have spotted that :D

Comment: Someone catched this in my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024872/make-anonymous-call-with-facebook-php-sdk

Comment: Thanks, @RoboRobok. Just got into the same trap, '2.6' instead of 'v2.6' :)

Comment: Ha! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in `default_graph_version`. It needs to be prefixed with v (standing for version), so the correct declaration is:

```
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
```