# Facebook Graph API: retrieve basic profile information without access_token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Just that, I'm reading the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) and it's seems like you can get access to the basic information without auth. But i'm getting an error

the code

```
$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => '...',
    'app_secret' => '...',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
]);

$response = $fb->get('/1000785'); // a valid ramdom user_id
```

and the response

```
Type: Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException
Message: You must provide an access token.
File: ...src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php
```

So, should I need to implement the "classic" login anyway?

Comment: How did you get the user_id?

Comment: it's a random number between a "valid range", i mean, with an access_token I can retrieve the information, it's a valid id.

Comment: Apps are using app scoped user IDs. Just because a User ID is valid in one app doesn't mean it will be valid in a different app.

Comment: There might be ways but it would depend on what you want to get from the user. For exemple a app token might work.

Comment: great!! @MathieudeLorimier i'm just google for app token i make it work, thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948809/trying-to-get-app-access-token

Comment: _"So, should I need to implement the "classic" login anyway?"_ - yes, because unless users actively decide to share their data with your app, it is none of your business.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just to clarify this issue. It's enough just generating an app access token.

**How to generate Facebook App Access Token?**

Simply, concatenating app_id and app_secret with a pipe symbol.

```
$appAccessToken = $config['app_id'] . '|' . $config['app_secret'];
$response = $fb->get('/0123456789', $appAccessToken);
```

Cheers!